# Selenium: element.get_property("textContent") returns empty string

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I'm trying to read some messages in Discord with selenium, but there a specific one that the webdriver seems unable to read.

```
chat_messages = browser.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "markup-eYLPri")
for chat_message in chat_messages:
    print(chat_message.get_property("textContent"))
```

I have tried with:

```
element.get_property("textContent")
element.get_property("innerText")
element.text
```

All of them return an empty string.

However, in the browser, I've tried running this javascript snippet:

```
e = document.getElementById("message-content-1008775068500893826")
e.innerText
e.textContent
```

And, they did print the text as expected.

Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

The second part of the *classname* i.e. `eYLPri` is dynamically generated and is bound to change sooner/later. They may change next time you access the application afresh or even while next application startup. So can't be used in locators.

---

### Solution

To print *`textContent`* you can use the `get_attribute()` method and of the element you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *css_selector*:

  ```
  chat_messages = browser.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[class^='markup']")
  for chat_message in chat_messages:
      print(chat_message.get_property("textContent"))
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  chat_messages = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[starts-with(@class, 'markup')]")
  for chat_message in chat_messages:
          print(chat_message.get_property("textContent"))
  ```

---

### Update

Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770041/7429447) and you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("textContent") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[class^='markup']")))])
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("textContent") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[starts-with(@class, 'markup')]")))])
  ```

Comment: Hello and thank you for your help! Unfortunately, I just tried these two options, and I'm still getting the same empty strings.

Comment: Checkout the answer update and let me know the status.